# Knowing the Interaction of Windows Batch files and Perl's system() function

Tags: perl

An example of BATCH file:

```
@echo off
echo starting
setlocal
cd c:\tmp
set A=B
perl -e "$ENV{X}='Y'; system('cmd')"
echo finished
```

I run this script (on Windows 7) with working directory set in `c:\.` 
The script opens, as expected, a new command shell with working directory set to `c:\tmp` and the environment set up as defined in my script.

As a next step I did Control-C within this shell where i was asked to  `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?.` 
Answering this with `Y,` I got the error message as :

`'Y' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I get, however, a shell prompt, the current directory shown as `c:\tmp`. Let's say I type Control-C again. Now I see:

```
c:\tmp>^C
finished
c:\>
```

My prompt shows that my working directory is back to `C:\ However`, this shell shows a funny behaviour If I repeatedly hit `ENTER` in this shell, 
I get the following output:

```
c:\>

c:\tmp>

c:\>

c:\tmp>
```

Furhter i came to know that I have two shells running, alternately getting my input:
 One with working directory set to `C:\`, the other one to `C:\tmp`.

Any idea what had happened here? Could someone having Windows 7 try out my example batch script with his/her Perl version? BTW, I was running it using Perl 5.8.8, since this is the version which is used in this project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I see the same behavior. The Ctrl+C somehow gets trough the foreground cmd.exe and is applied to the parent perl process, which possibly gets killed (depending on Y/N answer perl is killed together with batch job). When cmd is in interactive mode, it normally ignores Ctrl+C, so it seems to be a bug that it leaks to the parent process.

Side note: the result is that you are left with two cmd shells trying to read() the single terminal input. As soon as one reads a line, he processes it and another jumps in and gets a chance to read() a next line. And so on.

The workaround is to tell perl to ignore SIGINT:

```
perl -e "$SIG{INT} = 'IGNORE'; ... "
```

You would need to use `exit` to finish the foreground cmd instead of Ctrl+C.